# Get specific values from XML returned by web service

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, return

Guessing this is basic stuff, but I can't figure it out. I'm using a web service which returns the XML show below, but I've so far only dealt with web methods that return just a single string/int etc. I don't know how to deal with this being returned. Its the cdyne weather web service, and there are no in depth examples for a noob like me.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<ForecastReturn xmlns="http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Success>true</Success>
    <ResponseText>City Found</ResponseText>
    <State>NY</State>
    <City>New York</City>
    <WeatherStationCity>White Plains</WeatherStationCity>
    -<ForecastResult>
        -<Forecast>
            <Date>2014-09-20T00:00:00</Date>
            <WeatherID>2</WeatherID>
            <Desciption>Partly Cloudy</Desciption>
            -<Temperatures>
                <MorningLow>52</MorningLow>
            <DaytimeHigh>73</DaytimeHigh>
            </Temperatures>
            -<ProbabilityOfPrecipiation>
                <Nighttime>00</Nighttime>
                <Daytime>10</Daytime>
            </ProbabilityOfPrecipiation>
        </Forecast>
        -<Forecast>
            <Date>2014-09-21T00:00:00</Date>
            <WeatherID>3</WeatherID>
            <Desciption>Mostly Cloudy</Desciption>
            -<Temperatures>
                <MorningLow>63</MorningLow>
                <DaytimeHigh>78</DaytimeHigh>
            </Temperatures>
            -<ProbabilityOfPrecipiation>
                <Nighttime>10</Nighttime>
                <Daytime>20</Daytime>
            </ProbabilityOfPrecipiation>
        </Forecast>
    </ForecastResult>
</ForecastReturn>
```

Right now I'm just in need of the Description from the first forecast to stick in a label.

```
    weatherWebService.Weather weatherService = new weatherWebService.Weather();

    private void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        weatherService.GetCityForecastByZIP(txtZip.Text);

        lblDescription.Text = magicVariableX;
    }
```

The service has been added fine and can be called, I just don't have a clue whats being returned, as even when its a single variable string.int being sent back when tested in browser it is displayed as XML, but not treated as such in the code.

Comment: are you familiar with using the debugger..? you can also load that xml which is returned into a DataTable or DataSet and figure out what's what that way.. also if you are not familiar with how to read XML the internet is a widely under-utilized tool.. do a simple google search on how to read xml using C#.. also if you know the return type of the web service or not you could do something like this 
`var xmlData = weatherService.GetCityForecastByZIP(txtZip.Text);` also don't post code that won't appear to compile for example `lblDescription.Text = magicVariableX;` what is `magicVariableX`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you go down the path of trying to parse XML...
You're looking for the description of the first forecast returned, correct?

The method .GetCityForecastByZIP returns a type of "ForecastReturn" as opposed to "int" or "string" types.  This is a fairly common scenario.

I had success with this just a moment ago:

> ```
>         ForecastReturn fr = new ForecastReturn();
>         Weather service = new Weather();
>         fr = service.GetCityForecastByZIP("44060");
>         string YourMagicVariable = fr.ForecastResult[0].Desciption;
> ```

NOTE: Description is misspelled.  This is a typo on the CDYNE side of how they defined the type ForecastReturn.

Additionally, Because this is an .asmx service.  Make sure you reference the service as an old .net 2.0 service in "Advanced"

Comment: Splendid, I'm so new to this I felt completely lost. I was just trying out an XMLNodeList trying to SelectNodes and it said about "ForecastReturn", thank you :)